# Jackson Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.asText(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String`

Tags: java, json, jackson, jwt, glassfish-4

I tried to validate a JWT authentication token,

```
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256("secret")).withIssuer("siat").build();
String token=httpRequest.getParameter("token");
DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
```

following is exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.asText(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Which version of java-jwt are you using?

Comment: @KDavid-Valerio <version>3.1.0</version>

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your dependency graph whether it is pulling the correct version of 
Jackson-databind jar

The method it complains is available in version **2.4.0** onwards of **jackson-databind.jar**

If somehow you have the older version of jar in your classpath then it wouldn't serve the needed method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was a conflict between the dependency in my POM file and the GlassFish modules.

Comment: @CHHIBIAMOR Happy to help

Comment: Glassfish dependency was my problem too: glassfish-embedded-all.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the java-jwt dependencies in any maven repository, for example in [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.1.0) you'll se between the compile dependencies the required version of jackson-databind (that is the one throwing the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception).

In your case, for java-jwt 3.1.0 version you must have jackson-databind version 2.8.4 or the new one 2.9.0.